# Send email via echo command with data from variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

once a day a CSV is generated that includes a single column with several rows with names (one row for each name)
I want to send these names as an email to a certain distribution list.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

names=`cat /list_of_names.csv`

echo "$names" | mail -s "You got mail" "email@email.com"
```

The problem is that the email is always empty. It is correctly delivered with the right subject line, but there is no text in it.
When I check the variable manually in the console (echo "$names") all names are listed correctly.

Why is the email empty? Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Technically, there's no need for `names` at all; `mail -s "..." "email@email.com" < /list_of_names.csv` should do the same thing. `mail` simply reads its standard input for the body of the message. That said, there's nothing obvious about the code you've shown that would result in an empty body.

Comment: is `/list_of_names.csv` really at root, or should it be `./list_of_names.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have problems reading the file

```
cat /list_of_names.csv 2>&1 | mail -s "You got mail" "email@email.com"
```